# Alternating odd lines in a table

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to add `pure-table-odd` only to every odd table row. In Ruby on Rails I would use `cycle` for this. What is the best way to achieve this in Phoenix which takes the least amount of CPU power?

```
<%= for group <- @groups do %>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
    <td><%= group.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to get the index along with the group and check `rem(index, 2) == 1`:

```
<%= for {group, index} <- Enum.with_index(@groups) do %>
  <tr class="<%= if rem(index, 2) == 1, do: "pure-table-odd" %>">
    <td><%= group.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

A more fancy way using `Stream.zip` and `Stream.cycle`,
but most likely inefficient:

```
<%= for {group, class} <- Stream.zip(@groups, Stream.cycle(["", "pure-table-odd"])) do %>
  <tr class="<%= class %>">
    <td><%= group.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The " (double quote) of the class is getting escaped. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Please try the edited version. If you want the `class` to not be present at all (like my intention was in the original answer), you can add a call to `raw` around the string: `do: raw(~s| ... |)`.